# postgresql.conf and hba.conf in YugabyteDB YSQL?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

When I set up YugaByte I don't remember editing `ysql_hba.conf` or `postgresql.conf` - so I didn't set it up to allow connections from everywhere to its port 5433. But still, I am able to access it. That's not the case with regular Postgres. So how does this work? That said I am not able to connect to YB running on the same machine using `ysqlsh`, so looks like postgresql.conf does matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant tserver flags are `ysql_pg_conf_csv` and `ysql_hba_conf_csv` that generate `ysql_pg.conf` and  `ysql_hba.conf`. See docs: yugabyte.com/preview/secure

`hba.conf` is the one that determines authentication. For example, with `hba.conf`, you can specify which IPs can authenticate with which methods.